# Download not happened when the file size exceeding 1.5 MB

Tags: javascript, html, download, zip

I have a case, when a user click a download button, did some process and create a raw HTML content and make it download as zip file to the client side.

I tried the below code and it is working fine up to the `content` size is 1.5 MB. But if the `content` size is exceeding 1.5 MB it didn't download, as well as didn't show any error or warning.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = "Test.zip";
link.href = 'data:application/zip;base64,' + content;
link.click();
```

What may be the reason for that?

Comment: @Sirko: Doh! Yup, HTML5 spec [lists it](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download). On MDN it's marked "experimental should not be used in production code."

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

As Kizer suggested the problem seems to be about Data URI limitations.

This might be of help : [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

Answer (score 1):

You may be hitting a size limit in the data: URI scheme. Some browsers impose a limit on the size of the resource represented by a data: URI. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri.